# Displaying a php script result in a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am a beginner on coding. I am working on a WordPress website using beaver builder theme. My challenge is to display a login form (when the user is not logged in) and the user name when he is logged in, to a specific area of the header that has a class "header-text".
Here is my php code located in a file named "file.php"

```html
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 $var1 = "<p>Welcome <?php echo $user->display_name; ?></p>
   <p><a href='/login/login.php?logout=true'>Click here to log out</a></p>";
 $var2 = "<form action='login.php' method='post'>
      <input type='text" autocomplete='off' placeholder='Username' name='username'/>
      <input type='text' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Password' name='password'/>
      <button type='submit' value='Submit'>Submit</button>
   </form>";
 echo echo json_encode($var1);
} else {
 echo echo json_encode($var2);
}
?>
```

Here is javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 function displayAccess() {
    $.get("login/file.php");
    return false;
}

 if(<?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>) {
  var variable1 = <?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>;
  document.getElementByClassName("header-text").innerHTML = variable1; 
 }
 if(<?php echo json_encode($var2); ?>){
     var variable2 =  <?php echo json_encode($var2); ?>;
     document.getElementByClassName("header-text").innerHTML = variable2;
 }
});

</script>
```

I need help to correct my script. Thanks!

Comment: Its difficult to help when we do not know what exactly the problem is! Can you update your question to include an explanation of what the problem is that you are having?

Answer (score 0):

in this case, javascript an jquery is not necessary, because the login status changes on reload, anyway.

all you need is a change in your php code:

```php
<?php
/* put this to your template file (e.g. header.php) */

if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    /* change $var1 to echo it via html block inside php */
    ?>
    <p>Welcome <?php $user->display_name; ?></p>
    <p><a href="/login/login.php?logout=true">Click here to log out</a></p>
    <?php
    /* cut $var2 because it is not accessible in the else clause */
} else {
    /* 

    paste $var2 here and echo it

    btw: 
    * For tags that are self-closing, the forward slash should have exactly one space preceding it (https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/html/#self-closing-elements)
    * use single or double quotes – make a decision!

    */
    ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for re-ordering my php code. the fact is that I am using a third party theme (bb theme) and I could loose this snippet at the next update of the templete file.

Comment: I could put it directly in the module with the class "header-text" but the php script doesn't run there because it is a html module